# Can't view Rails app on Windows7 via mac local address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, networking, windows-7

My app runs on localhost:3000 on my mac
My mac has its own local address eee.local

Other computers in the office, including other windows machines
can connect to eee.local:3000 and use the the rails app.

However we had once case where one person's windows7 machine
could not connect. I brought a brand new windows7 machine for
IE testing purposes and it doesn't connect either.

I tried turning of the firewall and that doesn't work.
I tried using the ip instead eg. 192.160.0.3:3000 but that doesn't work.

I'm not really sure how else to check, or search for this problem
Anything Im overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing to try is to install iTunes. Sounds silly at first but installing iTunes gives your Windows machine Bonjour service discovery (enabled by default on Macs and Ubuntu desktops) which would let you resolve .local addresses.

Accessing via the IP really should have worked but if you've already turned off firewalls and the machines are on the same network then enabling Bonjour (by installing iTunes) is worth a shot.

Comment: I totally didn't understand what Bonjour actually did until I read this answer... The next question is would OS X block local requests that it can't verify the source through Bonjour?

Comment: Worked like a charm after I installed iTunes. I didn't have to turn of the firewall or anything fancy. Both the .local address and ip address worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other Windows machine on a different subnet? That could cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the web server to listen on all interfaces like so:

```
./script/server 0.0.0.0:3000
```

Comment: I tried this first, and this didn't work, installing iTunes was the solution.